# Error : context cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

having this following error : context cannot be resolved

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
PackageManager pm;
pm = getPackageManager();
//get a list of installed apps.
packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
     if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)continue;
        if(packageInfo.packageName.equals("mypackage")) continue;
          mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageInfo.packageName);
}
```

Comment: Did you initialize it ?

Comment: try just to remove it like this `ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)`

Comment: can you post whole codes?